# Boot camp: How do I reboot into Windows while in Windows if my default reboot is Mac?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

My default reboot is in Mac. Therefore to reboot *without pressing the <kbd>option</kbd> key during boot up*:

- Mac -> Mac: just reboot
- Mac -> Windows: Use [BootChamp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/28468/bootchamp)
- Windows -> Mac: just reboot
- Windows -> Windows: ???

*EDIT: Also I want to keep my default boot as Mac.*

In case it matters, I am running OS X Mountain Lion and Windows 7.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your default boot through Boot Camp.  Open the Control Panel and type "Boot Camp" in the search box, then open the Boot Camp disk drive icon and select the system you want booted.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I want to keep my default boot as Mac.

Comment: So change it back when you no longer want it to boot automatically into Windows.  Otherwise, deal with pressing the option key each time.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I hope there was a BootChamp-equivalent software for Windows too. It's nice to just reboot and not worry about having to press a key at the right time otherwise missing the OS reboot.